# add class to all images inside the content

Tags: theme-development, responsive, body-class

I have a function like this  :

```
function add_responsive_class($content)
{
    $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
    if (!empty($content)) {
        $document = new DOMDocument();
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $document->loadHTML(utf8_decode($content));

        $imgs = $document->getElementsByTagName('img');
        foreach ($imgs as $img) {
            $img->setAttribute('class', 'img-fluid');
        }

        $html = $document->saveHTML();
        return $html;
    }
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_responsive_class');
```

this adds `img-fluid` to all the images but also it removes the `align-left` , how can i modify the above function to add `img-fluid` to image instead of it removing the other classes?

like --> `<img class ="img-fluid align-left"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$img->setAttribute('class', 'img-fluid');
```

This sets the `class` field to a new value. Simply change this line to

```
$classes = $img->getAttribute('class');
$img->setAttribute('class', $classes . ' img-fluid');
```